# Is it possible to link PhoneAuth to an existing user account in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been working on a login process and woult like know if it is possible 
to link a PhoneAuthCredential to a existing Firebase user account.

Answer (score 0):

You can link a phone number to an existing Firebase user, provided the phone number is not already linked to another user.

Refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking#link-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account:

The credential you link is the phone credential here:
`mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)...`